# Does Uber compensate for users?

Tags: uber-api, business-logic

I was wondering if Uber would strategically give a particular APP a "cut" of the fee for sending users their way.

I can't really find any documentation on the uber site to support this except this one article and another Stackflow post that says Uber will reward it's affiliates $5 per new user they get to sign up.

If I'm generating a certain amount of riders per month for x amount of profit, would Uber give back a % of that?

Answer (score 0):

The Uber API is free to use, but there is not currently any public affiliate program in the style you are describing. There was previously a program that awarded $5 for a new US rider, but that program was deprecated earlier this year.

Hope that helps!